# What is the query to access the nodes in reverse to a relationship in neo4j

Tags: nosql, neo4j

I am using neo4j as my graph db. I am having some problem with the queries. Here is the scenario. 
I have an neo4j index = `users`.
I have all the user `nodes` in `users` index.
I have another index called "`comments`"
Every comment is a node.
And Every comment has a relationship "HAS_COMMENT" with user node.
So I have, `user_node ->HAS_COMMENT-> comment_node`

I can get all the comments of a user by this query.

```
$ start n = node:users(username='user1') match n-[r:HAS_COMMENT] -> a return a;
```

Now, I want to get in reverse direction. I have to get username from comment.
This is I am trying but getting null result.

```
$ start n = node:comments(_id='c101') match n-[r:HAS_COMMENT] -> a return a;
```

c101 is my comment id(node id); and it is present in db.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match arrows either way:

`start n = node:comments(_id='c101') match n-[r:HAS_COMMENT] -> a return a;`

`start n = node:comments(_id='c101') match n<-[r:HAS_COMMENT] - a return a;`

Comment: Thank you. Another question please, is it possible to delete an index node in neo4j. I cant find any query related to it. Thanks in advance

Comment: If by "index node" you just mean any other node that you  use as an index by creating special relationships from it to other things, there's nothing special about such nodes.   Check the help for the Cypher language, in particular the DELETE clause.   Also remember that you cannot delete a node until you've deleted all of its incident relationships first.

Comment: Old answer, I know, and with a deprecated and removed syntax, but there's a flaw here. In the graph, user have comments, so the pattern should always be specifying :HAS_COMMENT relationships are outgoing from users and incoming to comments. So since `n` is a comment and `a` is the user, I think the MATCH patterns should instead be: `match n<-[r:HAS_COMMENT] - a` and `match a-[r:HAS_COMMENT] -> n`